# Stack Program Counter

Tags: stacks, assembly

I am trying to understand stacks a little better.

I don't understand why the content of the program counter is saved on the stack for the function call (call), but not for a jump (jmp)?

can someone please explain it to me?

thanks in advance!

Comment: After a call, there is a return. Not after a jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, the program counter is just incremented i.e. the next instruction is executed. When you call a function, instead of the next instruction, some other instruction needs to be executed, and after completing the function you need to go back and execute the next instruction after the function call, hence it needs to be remembered. This is not the case with jump, where you are skipping some instructions, so no need to store program counter in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a `call`, you jump into a proceduce that can `ret`, effectively doing similar work to how a usual function call works. You run a function, and after it completes - you continue in the line after the `call`.

In contrast, `jmp` should not be called into procedures that use `ret`, which means that it will effectively act like a `goto` in C.

Both can be useful at times - `call` to call procedures / functions, and `jmp` (with its variations) to perform control flow operations, such as "if" conditions, "for" loops, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!